# React SRCSET for Responsive Images

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, srcset

I am trying to implement srcset with React and am using the following code:

```
<Image src={SmallImage} srcSet={`${SmallImage} 480w, ${LargeImage} 960w`} alt="Responsive Image" fluid/>
```

I'm mainly asking if I have implemented it correctly.
This is how the image renders on the browser:

```
<img src="/static/image-480w-3d9ff7c476c160ee3556eac821cdb4db.webp" srcset="/static/image-480w-3d9ff7c476c160ee3556eac821cdb4db.webp 480w, /static/image-960w-d968dc096ad43e327065e56fe306917f.webp 960w" alt="Responsive Image" class="img-fluid">
```

It seems as though the SmallImage is never loaded, even on mobile. As I'm using **fluid**, I understand that the image will resize itself - but I then wonder if it's worth using this method at all if the SmallImage (480 width) is never loaded.

[Test Page](https://gbcypmain.gatsbyjs.io/webinars/)

Comment: In the playground you provided, it uses the correct image, depending on viewport size, for me.

Comment: Oh really? When I viewed the page on mobile and tried to download the image - it was downloading the larger one.